# Returning a vector using with=TRUE

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `my.data.table` and a character vector `i` (length one) corresponding a to a colname of `my.data.table`. Using `i`, I would like to extract the corresponding column of `my.data.table` as a vector that is not of class `data.table` or `data.frame`.

How would I do this?

```
> my.data.table <- data.table(a=1:2,b=2:3)
> i <- "a"
> class(my.data.table[,i,with=FALSE])
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> as.vector(my.data.table[,i,with=FALSE])  ##does not work
   a
1: 1
2: 2
> is.vector(as.vector(my.data.table[,i,with=FALSE])) ##strange behavior
[1] FALSE
>
```

I assume there's a way to do this using `with=FALSE` and `eval(i, <env>)` in `j` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Marius is correct for a single column. `is.vector` returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes other than names. It returns FALSE otherwise. Both data.tables and data.frames are lists, and therefore vectors with many attributes

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the) for an explanation- once you've got a hang on the difference between `[` and `[[` these issues become much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either one of these will work in your example, but the second of the two is more generally useful.

```
my.data.table[[i]]
# [1] 1 2
my.data.table[,..i][[1L]]
# [1] 1 2
```

`..` in `data.table` means to "look up one level" (in this case for the variable `i`)

Comment: What's nice about the second statement is that it also works if the rows have to be subset as well: `my.data.table[2, i, with=FALSE][[1]]`. I am still waiting for `drop=TRUE` to be implemented, though.